# How can I full_join list list of list of dataframes

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I read multiple urls from a site and now have a list of list of data frames (tbl). Now I need to full_join these lists of data frames into one data frame.

```r
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(purrr)
library(rvest)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rvest'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     pluck


url <- file.path(str_c("https://amx.am/en/9/trading/10/instruments", '?page=', 1:3))
#> Error in str_c("https://amx.am/en/9/trading/10/instruments", "?page=", : could not find function "str_c"

tbl <- lapply(url, read_html) %>% lapply(html_table)
#> Error in UseMethod("read_xml"): no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "name"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `url` has multiple tables in them so to combine them together you can use

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map(url, ~read_html(.x) %>% html_table) %>%
   flatten() %>%
   bind_rows()
```

---

Or if you want to `full_join` them together, we can do that with `reduce`

```
map(url, ~read_html(.x) %>% html_table) %>%
  flatten() %>%
  reduce(full_join))
```