# How to automatically full_join list elements across lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-structures, dplyr

A simplified version of my data looks like this:

```
primary_list <- list(secondary_list = list(df1 = data.frame(df_name = "hello", time = c(1,2,3,6,7,9,12,20), v1 = sample(0:1, 8, replace = T)),
                                           df2 = data.frame(df_name = "world", time = c(1,5,6,8,9,12,15,18,19,20), v1 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = T))),
                                           
                     secondary_list2 = list(df1 = data.frame(df_name = "hello", time = c(1,5,6,8,9,12,15,18,19,20), v1 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = T)),
                                            df2 = data.frame(df_name = "world", time = c(4,6,7,8,12), v1 = sample(0:1, 5, replace = T))))
```

My objective is to `full_join` all the dataframes in the secondary_lists (i.e., the ones with a common element name and `df_name` identifier) to a *separate* dataframe by 'time'. The aim is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963678/dplyr-how-to-programmatically-full-join-dataframes-contained-in-a-list-of-list) but using a separate dataframe as the argument to `full_join`.

as a manual example, I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
time_df <- data.frame(time = 1:25)

expected_output <- list(
  secondary_list = list(time_df, primary_list$secondary_list$df1, primary_list$secondary_list2$df1) %>% reduce(full_join, by = "time"),
  secondary_list2 = list(time_df, primary_list$secondary_list$df2, primary_list$secondary_list2$df2) %>% reduce(full_join, by = "time")
)

### Ideally I'm aiming for something cleaned up like this:                

ideal_output <- lapply(expected_output, function(x){
  x <- x %>% select(time,v1.x,v1.y)
  colnames(x) <- c("time", "v1", "v2")
  x
})

### I can probably handle that after
```

I'm trying to make a solution that works with a much larger list structure and computes the `full_join` for all the secondary_list elements

I've tried flattening the list [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59907485/how-can-i-full-join-list-list-of-list-of-dataframes) but run into some complications indexing list elements sharing the same name. Also tried `rbindlist` to squash all the secondary lists into one dataframe but no joy there yet.

Solution does not have to be `dplyr`, just needs to work for n secondary_lists containing n dataframes of different lengths. For bonous points it would be great if the output does not repeat `df_name.x`, `df_name.y` as only one identifier column is necessary followed by the variables (see `ideal_output`) but I can clean that up afterwards easily enough.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
I got three great answers to the question.

- Ronak's is works great in a tidyverse pipeline workflow
- ekoam's is a one liner and I'm all for succinct code
- neon_ninja wins on the microbenchmark

Since I have a huge amount of data, speed is important so I'll accept neon_ninja's answer. Thanks all!

```
mbm = microbenchmark(
#####
ronak = primary_list %>%
  purrr::transpose() %>%
  map(~{
    .x$time_df <- time_df
    .x %>%
      reduce(full_join, by = 'time') %>% 
      select(time, df_name.x, starts_with("v")) ### Edited select fo n dfs
  }),

#####
ekoam = lapply(primary_list, compose(~select(., time, v1 = v1.x, v2 = v1.y), reduce), full_join, .init = time_df, by = "time"),
#####
neon_ninja = lapply(names(primary_list[[1]]), function(df_name) {
  time_df["df_name"] = df_name ### I added this to get a column of names
  time_df = data.frame(time = 1:25)
  for (sec_list_name in names(primary_list)) {
    time_df[sec_list_name] = NA
    df = primary_list[[sec_list_name]][[df_name]]
    for (i in 1:length(df$time)) {
      time_df[time_df$time == df$time[i], sec_list_name] = df$v1[i]
    }
  }
  time_df
})

)

#Unit: milliseconds
#       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#      ronak 11.572526 12.507490 15.132911 13.491643 16.531374 28.11236   100
#      ekoam 10.710731 11.464450 13.665370 12.450013 14.204986 26.83166   100
# neon_ninja  1.116033  1.258137  1.784428  1.345762  1.643547 13.89803   100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would solve this:

```
lapply(names(primary_list[[1]]), function(df_name) {
  time_df = data.frame(time = 1:25)
  for (sec_list_name in names(primary_list)) {
    time_df[sec_list_name] = NA
    df = primary_list[[sec_list_name]][[df_name]]
    for (i in 1:length(df$time)) {
      time_df[time_df$time == df$time[i], sec_list_name] = df$v1[i]
    }
  }
  time_df
})
```

If you need to find out your time range, here's a one liner to do that:

`range(unlist(lapply(unlist(primary_list, F, F), function(df) { df$time })))`

Similarly if you need to find out df names:

`unique(unlist(lapply(primary_list, names)))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `purrr::transpose` to get all the similar named dataframes in one list and then include `time_df` as a new dataframe in each list and do a `full_join`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

primary_list %>%
  purrr::transpose() %>%
  map(~{
    .x$time_df <- time_df
    .x %>%
        reduce(full_join, by = 'time') %>% 
        select(time, v1 = v1.x, v2 = v1.y)
    })
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I think this is pretty close to what I'm after but I do need the `full_join` to be to a separate dataframe and to keep the variables (v1.x, v1.y...) as columns. I'll edit the question a bit :).

Comment: @QAsena So you don't want `df_name` in the output? Can you check my updated answer if that is what you want?

Comment: yeah @Ronak Shah that's closer! But you see in the manual example, the `full_join` uses a separate `time_df` as the first argument for all the joins? I'm just trying to see where I can insert that as a unchanging argument into the `map`. @neon_ninja answer seems to work.

Comment: @QAsena Ok...I completely missed the `time_df` part. I have included that in the answer above.

Comment: Awesome! Some new syntax for me to learn in there. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
c(list(time_df), unlist(primary_list, False, False)) %>% reduce(full_join, by = "time")
```

**Update**

```
lapply(primary_list, compose(~select(., time, v1 = v1.x, v2 = v1.y), reduce), full_join, .init = time_df, by = "time")
```

Output

```
$secondary_list
   time v1 v2
1     1  1  1
2     2  0 NA
3     3  1 NA
4     4 NA NA
5     5 NA  1
6     6  1  0
7     7  1 NA
8     8 NA  1
9     9  0  0
10   10 NA NA
11   11 NA NA
12   12  0  0
13   13 NA NA
14   14 NA NA
15   15 NA  0
16   16 NA NA
17   17 NA NA
18   18 NA  0
19   19 NA  0
20   20  1  1
21   21 NA NA
22   22 NA NA
23   23 NA NA
24   24 NA NA
25   25 NA NA

$secondary_list2
   time v1 v2
1     1  1 NA
2     2 NA NA
3     3 NA NA
4     4 NA  1
5     5  0 NA
6     6  0  1
7     7 NA  1
8     8  1  1
9     9  1 NA
10   10 NA NA
11   11 NA NA
12   12  1  1
13   13 NA NA
14   14 NA NA
15   15  1 NA
16   16 NA NA
17   17 NA NA
18   18  1 NA
19   19  0 NA
20   20  0 NA
21   21 NA NA
22   22 NA NA
23   23 NA NA
24   24 NA NA
25   25 NA NA
```

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty close but returns 1 list where I'm expecting 2 (one list of all the df1s and another for the df2s) I'll edit the question to include a more complete expected output :)

Comment: Genius! Works great, appreciate it :)